# RBenv - creating a gemset

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, rbenv

Its a pretty straightforward question, so I'm trying to learn Ruby on Rails, I am following a tutorial, however they're saying that because they used RVM for the longest, they recommend to use RVM.

I have been using RBenv because the WSL installation recommends me to do so, and I'm confused on a part of the tutorial where it says `rvm use --create ruby-version@project`, that tells me that they're creating a gemset for project, but they're using rvm. I don't know what the equivalent command is for RBenv.

I am currently using Bundler 2.

My question is what is the equivalent command to `rvm use --create ruby-version@project`? And can you give me an example?

Please and thank you.

Comment: You don't have to create gemset, everything should work just by installing correct ruby version.

Answer (score 3):

By default rbenv does not support gemsets.

You need to set up [this](https://github.com/jf/rbenv-gemset) plugin to work with gemsets.

```
# Set up a default gemset for your project.
# Also will create a `.rbenv-gemsets` file in the current directory.
# NOTE: this will create the gemset under the current ruby version.
rbenv gemset init

# Alternatively, you can provide `rbenv gemset init` with the name of a gemset:
rbenv gemset init [gemset]

# To create a gemset under a specific ruby version:
rbenv gemset create [version] [gemset]

# You can list the existing gemsets by using the following command:
# This should include the most recent gemset you just created.
rbenv gemset list

# You can delete a gemset with the following command:
rbenv gemset delete [version] [gemset]
```